# WinRT with sqlite concerns

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime

I'm trying to make a windows 8 app with SQLite for the database. The problem is I have a table with 26k rows of existing data, that's about a 13mb file. I need to build that into the package so it can be read/wrote to. All the solutions I see are saying to copy the file from install location to the app data folder. The only solution I could think is check to see if the file exists in the app data and if it doesn't copy it, which would mean only the first start up the app would have a 10 second or so hang. But there has got to be a better way of doing it than recopying the file?

Comment: Show an Indeterminate progress bar before you start the copy.  10 seconds is nothing considering what you're doing.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780619.aspx

Comment: I suppose that could work. I know winrt it is a bit restricted on what you can do, but I just thought I'd see if anyone had any sort of creative solution.